# How and where to change mouse button behaviour in a special mode

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude

In Markdown mode with flyspell enabled, `mouse-2` bound to `mouse-yank-primary` is also bound to `flyspell-correct-word`, the flyspell function that displays in a menu correction propositions. If the buffer is empty, the menu is displayed, if not, its content is yanked. Grrr.

I spent some time trying to find where to change this second binding but as I'm not an emacs guru, I just got lost. I tried `(global-set-key "S-mouse-2" #'flyspell-correct-word)` in `~/.emacs.d/init.el` but I didn't manage to get anything working properly.

So the question is how and where to bind say `S-mouse-2` to that function. A better solution would be to keep both bindings but to prioritize the menu over yanking when the mouse is over a word that needs correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my GNU Emacs 25.2.2 the command (executed from the `*scratch*` buffer)

```
(global-set-key "S-mouse-2" #'flyspell-correct-word)
```

pops up the debugger. However,

```
(global-set-key [S-mouse-2] #'flyspell-correct-word)
```

works, as also

```
(global-set-key [S-mouse-2] 'flyspell-correct-word)
```

You can check the effect with:

```
(global-key-binding [S-mouse-2])
```

Comment: I'm using version 24.5.1. it works with `(global-set-key [S-mouse-2] 'flyspell-correct-word)`. Thanks